# May I post a question whose code is written in a programming language about which nothing exists in Code Review Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions, questions, specific-language

May I post a question whose code is written in a programming language about which nothing exists in Code Review Stack Exchange?

For example, [Asymptote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote_(vector_graphics_language)) is a vector graphics programming language which, in addition to its nice integration with LaTeX and friends, is capable of generating 3D rendered artworks. It seems that no question about Asymptote has been asked in this community, nor is there any tag associated with it.

Thus, can I post anything including Asymptote code? and if so, what tag should I consider for that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, as long as it's clearly a *programming* language, and [not purely configuration or markup](/q/6060/75307).  From your description of Asymptote, it sounds that it is fine in this respect.

As a new user (less than 300 reputation points), you're not able to write a new tag of your own choosing in the "tags" box.  However, you can post without it (though you need at least one tag) and add a comment asking a more experienced user to create the tag for you.  In the unlikely case that you don't get that help, then *flag* your question for moderator assistance.

Fair warning: you might need some patience waiting for reviews if the language isn't well-known.  Don't let that put you off!